# Apache wicket: how to add a zero padding to DateTimeField?

Tags: apache, datetime, wicket

I've got a page with DateTimeField. 
When i'm filling only date field (leaving hours and minutes fields empty) and have a validation error (page get's reloaded, feedback panel is shown), time fields got filled in with 0:00. But the thing is, that I want to have 00:00.
As I inspected, minutes field got ZeroPaddingIntegerConverter(2), so I just simply add it to hours field. But the thing is I cannot add anything to hours field as it is private.

So is there a way to add a ZeroPaddingIntegerConverter(2) to a hours field in DateTimeField of Apache Wicket ?

Comment: can you show some code? And, witch DateTimeField are talking about (wich package, there are 2). DateTimeField has a format parameter ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the DateTextField provided in the org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form package

```
DateTextField myDateTextField = DateTextField("endTime", "HH:mm");
```

You can define a date pattern that will be used for formatting the date. The time will be displayed with two digits for the hour and a leading zero if necessary.